# Quelle est l'origine de l'expression "Faire le poirier" ?

Tags: expressions, étymologie

L'expression *Faire le poirier* signifie se tenir en équilibre sur les mains, les pieds en l'air et la tête en bas. Pourquoi cette expression fait-elle allusion à un arbre, et pourquoi le poirier plutôt qu'un autre ?

Comment: D'après le [ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=faire+le+poirier&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=7&smoothing=3) l'expression semble être apparue vers le milieu du 19ème. Sur Gallica aussi. Et sans doute pas que en France, puisqu'on la trouve dans les possédés de dostoievsky. Mais impossible de trouver pourquoi le poirier.

Comment: Je pense que la réponse est à chercher dans la forme des jambes et aussi dans le fait que le poirier est, à ma connaissance, le seul arbre fruitier qui se cultive attaché contre un mur (cela ne se pratique plus beaucoup à l'époque de l'agriculture industrielle), où il prend une forme caractéristique.

Comment: D'autres langues ont choisi des arbres plus adaptés à leur climat. En castillan et en catalan, on "fait le pin". Pourquoi ? Le mystère est encore plus épais que pour le français puisqu'on ne peut pas dans ce cas se raccrocher aux palmettes ou à la taille de l'arbre.

Comment: https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/20446/por-qu%C3%A9-hacer-el-pino-es-poner-el-cuerpo-verticalmente-con-los-pies-hacia-arr

Answer (score 6):

Probablement parce que cette expression provient d'une région où les poiriers sont prédominants.

Une explication un peu différente pourrait être un rapprochement vers l'expression "être bonne poire" qui définit quelqu'un de naïf. Ainsi "faire le poirier" serait quelqu'un qui feint la naïveté. Expression qui aurait pu dérivée ensuite? (Tout ceci n'est qu'hypothèse bien entendu, mais je trouve ça intéressant. [lien](http://www.expressio.fr/expressions/etre-une-bonne-poire.php) )

Le [TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/poirier) donne :

> Faire le poirier ou l'arbre fourchu*. Se tenir en équilibre sur les mains, le corps vertical, la tête appuyée sur le sol et les pieds écartés l'un de l'autre. Un soir d'été (...) elle a pris le sentier au bord de la rivière. Trois gamins, qui sortaient de l'eau, faisaient le poirier fourchu sur l'herbe (Martin du G.,Vieille Fr., 1933, p.1049).

Indiquant clairement la référence à l'arbre en général. Mais pas pourquoi cet arbre.

La [poire](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/poire) c'est aussi la tête. D'où peut-être le choix de ce fruit pour dire qu'on à la tête en bas.

Answer (score 5):

Le poirier semble exister sous plusieurs formes :

[image: Formes de poirier]

Et ça pourrait être aussi bien la quenouille pour les jambes :

[image: Quenouille]

[image: D'autres font le parallèle]

Que les palmettes (*a.k.a.* taille en espalier) pour les bras :

[image: Palmettes]
<sub>(source: [pepiniere-jardin.com](https://pepiniere-jardin.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/09/Poirier-paliss%C3%A9-palmette-verriers.jpg))</sub>

<sub>J'ai trouvé que le pommier aussi semblait pouvoir se tailler en espalier, peut-être que ça soutient la quenouille…</sub>

<sup>[Une des sources.](https://spkfrnch.wordpress.com/2011/12/02/regarde-maman-je-fais-le-poirier-boum/)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Je pense que le poirier est utilisé de préférence à un autre arbre à cause de (l'ancienne tradition de) la taille en palmettes : on pourrait voir dans les palmettes les bras pliés qui supportent le reste du corps.